# IndexError: narray: index out of range (While working with Ocropus)

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am working with ocropus for the purpose to binarize and segments the unsegmented images.
I use command to binarize the image files by ocropus as

`ocropus-binarize -o book /home/images/*.tif`

By using the above mentioned command it worked fine for few images but after sometime it prompts an error message as shown below,

```
File "/usr/local/bin/ocropus-binarize", line 151, in <module>
   result = pool.map(process1, jobs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py"
   return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 517, in get
   raise self._value
IndexError: narray: index out of range
```

Any help regarding the matter would be highly appreciative.

Comment: Looks like a bug in OCRopus. Are you using the latest version?

Comment: Yes, I have latest version of Ocropus i.e., 0.4.4

Comment: I'd report this to the authors if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not related specifically to OCRopus, but to this error in general for future google searches.

The multiprocessing module splits work into chunks and sends each chunk to a worker process. Work is executed in a block that looks like this:

```
try:
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
except Exception, e:
    result = (False, e)
```

Where `func()` is either `apply()` or `map()` depending on whether you used `pool.apply()` or `pool.map()` and args and kwds contain both the function you want to run and the data you want to run it on.

If your function raises an exception, instead of bugging out the worker process directly, that error is passed back to the process that manages all workers as a result tuple. The main process sees this (on multiprocessing.py:517 as reported above, which depends on the Python version) and re-raises the original exception from your function.

This is an error in *your* function, possibly on a single piece of data. Unfortunately the line number of the original exception is not reported, which makes debugging a bit trickier.